# Unknow custom element error during passing component as a prop in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Could you explain why Vue tells me, that `Unknown custom element: <MyComponent> - did you register the component correctly?` here:

```
const CustomComponent = Vue.component('CustomComponent', {
  template: '<div>test</div>'
})

const RenderComponent = Vue.component('RenderComponent', {
  props: {
    component: {
        type: [Function, String]
    }  
  },
  template: '<component :is="component"></component>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    MyComponent: CustomComponent,
    RenderComponent
  },
  template: '<render-component component="MyComponent"></render-component>'
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2qobuj4y/1/

How to pass components to a prop properly here? Are there some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyComponent` doesn't exist so you don't want to list it in your app's `components`.  Change your app code to:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    CustomComponent, // Not actually being used, the template passes a string
    RenderComponent
  },
  template: '<render-component component="CustomComponent"></render-component>'
})
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/h3tq6eoy/)

**Explanation**

You have properly registered `CustomComponent` as `MyComponent` in the main `app` component, and you could use it directly in its template.  But then you are also passing a **string** with the value "MyComponent" to the `RenderComponent` component.  `RenderComponent` then tries to instantiate a `MyComponent` component, but none exists in the global scope where it is looking for it.  (It only exists with that name within the main `app` component where you registered it.)

Alternatively, if you were to use a binding instead when you pass `MyComponent` (i.e. `:component` instead of `component`) it still would not work because you can't pass `components` as props.

(EDIT:  You can but not the traditional way.  This works:  `:foo="$options.components.foo"`.  See [this comment from Evan You](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/754))

**Interesting Alternative**

You mentioned trying to pass it from `data` instead, and while I can't say if it's a good practice, it does work.  It could get uglier if you ever migrated to single-file components where you wouldn't have access to a global scope, and it's a little confusing, but it does work:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    MyComponent: CustomComponent // Taken from global scope
  },
  components: {
    // CustomComponent, // No need in this version
    RenderComponent
  },
  template: '<render-component :component="MyComponent"></render-component>'
})
```

[Here is that fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/h3tq6eoy/19)

Comment: But I've registered component with name 'MyComponent'. Why it doesn't work?

Comment: I added a more elaborate explanation to my answer.

Comment: Is it a good practice to add to `data()` method the link to a component?

Comment: I can't say whether it's a good practice, but it does work: [jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/h3tq6eoy/19](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/h3tq6eoy/19/)

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not sure that the following statement is correct: `it still would not work because you can't pass components as props.`.

Comment: Even the creator of Vue says that it's possible: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/754

Comment: Interesting, I only knew that you couldn't pass them the traditional way.  I'll edit my answer.  Thanks for the link